# WebClient - ServiceSecurityContext.Current.WindowsIdentity = null

Tags: wcf, rest, authentication, webclient

I have a WCF service (which accesses a database) on a Windows 2008 (IIS 7.5) machine, called from Excel (VSTO - the Excel client resides on an internal network) via WebClient (uses a GET call via REST/webHttpBinding).

I am wanting to pass the user's credentials to the WCF service - I then want the method within the service to access the database as the person who is logged onto the workstation that Excel is initiated from however I am getting back a 401 (Unauthorized).

On the client I have (note "base" refers to the WebClient class which my class inherits):-

```
        base.Credentials = CredentialCache.DefaultCredentials;
        base.OpenReadCompleted += new OpenReadCompletedEventHandler(ReadJsonStringAsyncComplete);
        base.OpenReadAsync(new Uri(address));
```

Within the service I have:-

```
    [OperationContract]
    [WebInvoke(Method = "GET", UriTemplate = "/GetSomeData", RequestFormat = WebMessageFormat.Json, ResponseFormat = WebMessageFormat.Json)]
    SomeDataClass GetSomeData();
```

Service config:-

```
  <service name="zzzz.Service.xxxx.xxxx" behaviorConfiguration="DataExtractBehavior">
      <endpoint address="" binding="webHttpBinding" bindingConfiguration="DataExtractBinding" behaviorConfiguration="MyEndpointBehavior" contract="zzzz.Service.xxxx.Ixxxx">
    </endpoint>
  </service>
  ...
  <serviceBehaviors>
    <behavior name="DataExtractBehavior">
      <serviceMetadata httpGetEnabled="true" />
      <serviceDebug includeExceptionDetailInFaults="true" />
      <etwTracking profileName="EndToEndMonitoring Tracking Profile" />
    </behavior>
  </serviceBehaviors>
  ...
  <webHttpBinding>
    <binding name="DataExtractBinding">
      <security mode="TransportCredentialOnly">
        <transport clientCredentialType="Windows" ></transport>
      </security>
    </binding>
  </webHttpBinding>
</bindings>
...
```

ConnectionString includes `"integrated security=SSPI"`

**Notes:**

- When I call a dummy method that simply returns a string (no database calls) I get a successful response (no problems)
- Inside the WCF service as far as I can see (through tracing) it is falling over on the database calls (probably because it can't logon/authenticate with the database)
- Also inside the WCF methods the ServiceSecurityContext.Current.WindowsIdentity seems to be null
- I can access methods within the service when it is hosted on my workstation (connects to a local instance of the database) : the problems arise when I deploy to a Development machine that I don't have the same priviledges on
- I've tried NetworkCredentials (default and hardcoded userIs/password/domain)
- I have Windows Authentication and ASP.NET Auth enabled (I've tried just Windows Auth with Anon/ASP.NET/nothing-else with mixed results - never successful just a different return code)
- Impersonation is current not set however I have tried it set to true (received 500)

Does anyone know how to successfully send the user's credentials in the above scenario (and hence resolve the HTTP 401 issue).

Regards
Travis